# HTML Table Alternating Row THBody Usage

Tags: html, css

I have several html tables in my content area of my page. The style is weird because it doesn't start the alternating row color fresh at the start of each table, it carries it on through out the list of tables.

```
<table>
    <tr>
       Blue
    </tr>
    <tr>
       White
    </tr>
    <tr>
       Blue
    </tr>
</table>

<table>
    <tr>
        White
    </tr>
    <tr>
        Blue
    </tr>
    <tr>
        White
    </tr>
</table>
```

The colour in the rows is a representation of what the css would set as the row background. But I want css to start the alternating again for the next table. So it would be:

```
<table>
    <tr>
       Blue
    </tr>
    <tr>
       White
    </tr>
    <tr>
       Blue
    </tr>
</table>

<table>
    <tr>
        Blue
    </tr>
    <tr>
        White
    </tr>
    <tr>
        Blue
    </tr>
</table>
```

Does `THBODY` have anything to do with it?

Thanks,

CSS Code

```
table { border-collapse:collapse; text-align:center; }

table th, td { border:1px solid #759EC7; padding:3px 7px 2px; }

th { color: #fff;
background-color: #5c87b2; text-align:center; }

tr:nth-child(odd) { background-color: #CEE1F5; }
tr:nth-child(even) { background-color: #fff; }
```

**Update**
It may be a bug that has crept in, I've look on the suggested fiddles and it works perfectly so it is just some buggy code somewhere.

Comment: Can you post your CSS as well please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue I was having was with two `<TH>` rows, which through off the alternating row colouring. So for example:

```
<tr>
    <th colpsan="2">Name</th>
</tr>
<tr>
    <th>First</th>
    <th>Last</th>
</tr>
```

This would have the `Blue` start on the `Name` row and then start alternating. So the first line of the table body would be `Blue`

```
<tr>
    <th>Name</th>
</tr>
```

This would have the `Blue` start on the `Name` row like before and then start alternating, **However**, the first line of the table body would be `White`

In these situations it would show a changing style which is not what I wanted to achieve. So all I did to fix this is:

```
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th colpsan="2">Name</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th>First</th>
        <th>Last</th>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
   <!-- Table Content in Here -->
</tbody>
```

And I then changed the style sheet to be:

```
tbody tr:nth-child(odd) {}
tbody tr:nth-child(even) {}
```

So basically I used the `TBody` and `THead` tags to make a more specific css style which is brilliant. More control, flexibility. So in my new example, you can have as many rows in the `THead` as you like, the content should always start on `White`, and to answer my question:

> Does `THead` have anything to do with it?

Yes, it has **EVERYTHING** to do with it.

Answer (score 4):

You can easily achieve it using combinations of `:nth-child()` by passing `even` and `odd` values. For eg. see [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ewtcq/).

where, the CSS is

```
body {
    background-color: black;
    color: red;
}
table tr:nth-child(odd) {
    background-color: blue;
}
table tr:nth-child(even) {
    background-color: #ffffff;
}
```

Comment: I think I may have had a bug creep in somewhere. It does show it working perfectly

Answer (score 2):

The only problem you have is missing the  tag in the table.
It works perfectly if you add it. It shouldnt have anything to do with the tbody tag.

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>Blue</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>White</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Blue</td>
    </tr>
</table>
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>Blue</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>White</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Blue</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

[here is the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/rBwBm/](http://jsfiddle.net/rBwBm/)

Comment: No I didn't miss the tag, it was a text representation of the colour that should be portrayed in that row

Comment: well, representation or not, this markup should work ... I put it into jsfiddle and it works with your css.

Comment: I'm sorry but from my perspective a TR with no TD is not valid HTML, so yes in your example you're missing the TD tags...

Comment: Thats the point. I know its not valid markup, its not the point of my question, if you read it. I'm very experienced with HTML, I would not forget to put `TD` tags in. It was just a text representation of the colour that the row should have been.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're doing it using javascript, right ? Probably getting a collection of tr through jquery with $('tr') ? Try using CSS nth-child(odd) and nth-child(even) instead, most modern browsers won't have any problem with that.

Comment: no, look at my question, its done in css, anyway I think it maybe a bug